# Show data from Google Directions API on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I've got the JSON data from Google Directions API. How can I show this route on map using Google Maps API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) and [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#RenderingDirections), you can avoid getting the JSON data from the Google Directions API (the Google Maps Javascript API v3 DirectionsService returns a JSON result that the DirectionRenderer can display directly).

See this [example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

Comment: I need to ask Google Directions API for a JSON data and then store it in the database. Can I use this data to load into Google Maps API?

Comment: Please read the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) (10.1.3).  My understanding is you can only save data like that in your database temporarily, but IANAL.  I have seen discussions of serializing that response, storing it an using it later, haven't done it myself.