# Using Maps JavaScript API with response from Google Maps Directions API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use Maps JavaScript API with response from Google Maps Directions API to display driving routes passing some waypoints.

I wrote this code below to get waypoints' order using Google Maps Directions API, which is working well.

*google_directions.rb*

```
def initialize(origin, destination, waypoints, opts=@@default_options)
    　　@origin = origin
    　　@destination = destination
    　　@waypoints = 'optimize:true' + waypoints
    　　@options = opts.merge({:origin => @origin, :destination => @destination, :waypoints => @waypoints})

　　@url = @@base_url + '?' + @options.to_query + '&key=' + Rails.application.secrets.google_maps_api_key

　　@response = open(@url).read
　　@jdata = JSON.parse(@response)
　　@status = @jdata['status']
end

def public_response
    @response
end
```

Now, I get json response(@response) from Google Maps Directions API, so I want to reuse it to display the routes on the google map with Maps JavaScript API.

*index.html.erb*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    toRender(<%=raw @response.to_json %>)
  });
  function toRender(response){
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
</script>
```

I'm gessing I should pass @response to directionsDisplay.setDirections() as an argument, but it's not working. Could anyone show me the best way to solve this??

I found this Q&A, which says I need to translate the JavaScript API JSON response into a DirectionsResult object. Does anyone know how to do it??

[Displaying results of google direction web service without using javascript api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450061/displaying-results-of-google-direction-web-service-without-using-javascript-api?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here is my Google Maps Directions API response from @url request.

[Google Maps Directions API Response](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?destination=%E5%AF%8C%E5%B1%B1%E7%9C%8C&mode=driving&origin=%E5%AF%8C%E5%B1%B1%E7%9C%8C&sensor=false&waypoints=optimize%3Atrue%7C36.8723969%2C137.4323206%7C36.583206%2C137.4441982%7C36.6755751%2C136.8686222%7C36.815002%2C137.586191%7C36.94619%2C137.5599425%7C36.8715082%2C137.4480303%7C36.583206%2C137.4441982%7C36.583206%2C137.4441982&key=AIzaSyCXdc1buaRyXcQtDaNSVEnK0yE9dMOpWDU)

Comment: related question: [Show data from Google Directions API on Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503246/show-data-from-google-directions-api-on-google-maps)

Comment: possible duplicate of [error in displaying Directions webservice result on to the google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921878/error-in-displaying-directions-webservice-result-on-to-the-google-map)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the json response link in the question.